# How to share global variables between files in Python like C

Tags: python, extern

i have 2 files

```
#foo.py
 global x
 def foo():
   x = 8


#main.py
from conf import *

 if __name__ == "__main__":
 foo()
```

how to get the X value in  main.py file i have to use only 2 files here 
now if print or store x to other variable it has to print 8

Comment: `foo` is not assigning to a global `x`, since it does not define `x` to be global.  The `x` within `foo` is local to `foo`.  To make it global, it needs to be declared global inside the function, not outside of it.  Move the global declaration to be inside of `foo`.

Comment: i have done but no change

Comment: For starters, you have to put some form of `input foo` in `main.py`. Or is `conf` a typo for `foo`?

Comment: Well, that's only part of the problem.  Try changing the import to `import foo`, then you can do `foo.foo()` and then examine `foo.x` and you should see it, provided it's global (which in the posted code it is not).

Comment: -@TomKarzes we can't do like that gives errors

Comment: @Yashvanth It doesn't give errors.  I'm assuming the file name is `foo.py`.  I don't know what `conf.py` is.  If you have `foo.py`, then `import foo` should work.  If you can't get that much to work, then you have much more basic problems than accessing global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to get varaible x in main.py , if you declare x as global inside `foo()`  that mean you will be accessing the global x not local x.

```
#foo.py
 x =10
def foo():
   x = 8
   print(" in foo x= " ,x)


#main.py
from conf import *
from foo import x, foo

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(" x imported from foo.py  = ", x)
   foo()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
x imported from foo.py  =  10
in foo x=  8
```

Comment: from foo import x, foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
i got this error

Comment: I can run this code successfully on my machine , make sure foo.py and main.py are in same folder

Comment: but the  i need x value 8 not 10

Comment: then you should use simply add a  `return x`   statement in `foo()` and in main.py call foo as `somevariable = foo()` and now this some variable will be the value of x i.e 8 and you can use it any where in youe main.py

Comment: but if have to access more then one variables in foo function like
x = 8 and y =15 in this seniority what will be solution

Comment: In python you can return more than one , `return x, y ` or you can return a list with number of variables  :)

Comment: and in main.py `somex, somey = foo` , Plz  accept and upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the global keyword properly

```
# foo.py
x = None

def foo():
    global x
    x = 8

#main.py
# this imports everything from foo in main
from foo import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
foo()
print(x)
```

Comment: how to access the x value in main.py files

Comment: you imported everything from foo with * wildcard so you can access it normally in main.py. just do print(x)